# Problems converting Dynamic Web Project to Maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I'm using Eclipse Luna with Websphere Application Sever 8.5.

When I run a dynamic web project using the Websphere Application Sever 8.5 it runs fine.

However, when I convert a dynamic web project to a maven project, i'm getting around **53 errors** starting with `Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere` e.g **`Missing artifact com.ibm.websphere.xml:xmlapi:jar:1.0.0' all located in my pom.xml`**.

I am also getting this error:

- `The container 'Maven Dependencies' references non existing library`
  `C:\Users\Brian242\.m2\repository\com\ibm\websphere\ws\com.ibm.ws.wccm\1.0.0\com.ibm.ws.wccm-1.0.0.jar`'

Not sure if that's part of the problem.

I've looked everywhere for a solution but haven't found anything. So I have decided to ask for some help. Does anyone know how to solve the above problem/s?

Thank you,
Brian

```html
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>TrialProj</groupId>
  <artifactId>TrialProj</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.ibm.tools.target</groupId>
      <artifactId>was</artifactId>
      <version>8.5.5</version>
      <type>pom</type>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>3.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.6</source>
          <target>1.6</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.4</version>
        <configuration>
          <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 0):

you created M2_REPO environment variable?

- right click on the project root
- Build Path-> Configure Puild Path ...
- Click button 'Add Variable'
- Click 'Set Variable ...'
- Click 'New ...'
- name: M2_REPO
- Path: / path_to_repository_the_maven /
- Click Ok
- Recompile

Comment: Thanks for respoding.
I went into 'Add Variable' from the build path, and I see 'M2_REPO - C:\Users\Brian242\.m2\repository' in there.

Comment: are you sure that the repository is there?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse make sure you add suport for eclipse web tools using:

```
mvn eclipse:eclipse -Dwtpversion=2.0
```

(2.0 or your required version) And afterwards recompile maven project:

```
mvn compile
```